# Nuget packages.config - 3rd Party dll's are not copied to the output directory

Tags: nuget, nuspec

When I add my nuget package to a project with a package reference it works fine but when I add it to a project with a packages.config file the third party dll 'Software.Interop.program.dll' is not copied to the output directory.

Here's my nuspec:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>$Id$</id>
        <version>$Version$</version>
        <title>$Title$</title>
        <authors>$Authors$</authors>
        <owners>MyCompany</owners>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>$Desc$</description>
        <summary>$Summary$</summary>
        <releaseNotes>$ReleaseNotes$</releaseNotes>
        <copyright>Copyright ©  2018</copyright>
        <dependencies />
        <contentFiles>
            <files include="bin\Release\Software.Interop.program.dll"
                    buildAction="None"
                    copyToOutput="true"
                    flatten="true" />
        </contentFiles>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="bin\Release\Software.Interop.program.dll"
            target="lib\net471" />
    </files>
</package>
```